# Error "module not found: jakarta.cdi" when using module-info.java in a Spring boot 3 project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-module

I got the following error when I add the dependency `jakarta.transaction` to the `module-info.java` file, as suggested by IntelliJ:

```
module not found: jakarta.cdi
```

The module-info.java file dependency is added like this:

```
module myModule.main {
...
requires jakarta.transaction;
}
```

The project builds and runs well without the `module-info.java` file, so I guess all dependencies are well defined at `gradle.build` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import instruction that triggered the IntelliJ to suggest the dependency was this:

```
 import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
```

In this case, the import should had be from `springboot` instead :

```
 import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

I post this answer in case some else fall into this rare problem with no obvious solution.